# mongodb poor query performance and profiler estimates very high

Tags: mongodb, performance, profiler

My mongodb database is roughly 50Gi in size. There are approximately 45K collections ranging wildly in size. the largest has on the order of < 1Million documents.

I'm running mongodb version 3.6.8 in AWS on r5.xlarge (32Gi memory, 4 vCPU) with a 500Gi gp2 SSD disk mounted as a persistent volume. It is *not* sharded, but replicated with 1 Primary and 2 Secondary nodes.

Much of the time the queries perform reasonably well. However, every so often queries (inserts, updates, fetches--it doesn't seem to matter) take a "very long time" to complete. I am trying to figure out what is causing this.

I enabled profiling for queries that take longer than 10 seconds.

Here is a case in point that boggles the mind. It is an update on a collection with 5 documents where the qualification is on the _id property. It takes 20 seconds to run. The profiler shows:

```
{
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "bar.PumpStatus__PumpEventDrivenAppNS",
    "command" : {
        "q" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e43f4b9aae591154193999a")
        },
        "u" : {
            "$inc" : {
                "foo_version" : 1
            },
            "$set" : {
                "PumpId" : "Pump1",
                "Temp" : NumberLong(197),
                "RPMS" : NumberLong(3885),
                "Time" : ISODate("2020-03-04T20:39:11.065Z"),
                "foo_modifiedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-04T20:39:11.946Z"),
                "foo_modifiedBy" : "439b96af-558e-4372-a7b9-d245f48d3d3d"
            }
        },
        "multi" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    },
    "keysExamined" : 1,
    "docsExamined" : 1,
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nModified" : 1,
    "writeConflicts" : 1,
    "numYield" : 1,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(3),
                "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "millis" : 20001,
    "planSummary" : "IDHACK",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "UPDATE",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 20008,
        "works" : 3,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 1,
        "needYield" : 1,
        "saveState" : 1,
        "restoreState" : 1,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 1,
        "nWouldModify" : 1,
        "nInvalidateSkips" : 0,
        "wouldInsert" : false,
        "fastmodinsert" : false,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IDHACK",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 18351,
            "works" : 1,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 3,
            "restoreState" : 2,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "keysExamined" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 1
        }
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2020-03-04T20:39:31.948Z"),
    "client" : "10.10.158.164",
    "appName" : "io.myorg.mongodb",
    "allUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "foo",
            "db" : "bar"
        }
    ],
    "user" : "foo@bar"
}
```

mongodb *estimates* that using IDHACK to find the document will require 18.351 seconds and that the overall execution will take 20.008 seconds. Lo and behold the execution time clocked in at 20.001.

I find these numbers difficult to believe. can they be trusted? and if so, what could possibly be happening to cause such a slow execution time?

the collection is very small, there is no reported lock wait, if i run the equivalent find by hand, it returns instantly. as near as I can tell the CloudWatch metrics for the volume do not indicate very slow read or write operations. latencies are low and IOPS nowhere near the limit.

areas that i know can be improved:

- enable `directoryForIndexes` to split collections and indexes across 2 volumes
- use `XFS` on the volume
- ensure huge pages are disabled (i think they are)

I'm skeptical that any of the above will relieve the pain. i suspect that i am doing something (else) basic completely wrong.

any thoughts on what might be happening here?

Comment: could it be a noisy neighbor on AWS stealing your cpu time?

Comment: i can't rule out a noisy neighbor. i am moving to a larger instance (different and maybe fewer neighbors)

Comment: might pay to upgrade mongodb too while you're at it.